# After checking in luggage for upcoming American flight, can I get between Terminal 7 and Terminal 8 at JFK

Tags: jfk

I plan to check my luggage at Terminal 8 for my American Airline flight out of JFK.  However, I would like to use the Alaska Airline Lounge in Terminal 7.  Can I get from Terminal 8 to 7 & back again & how is that done?  Walking, shuttle, going in & out through Security check again & again, or what?  How much time to allow for each direction?  Thanks in advance for your response.

Comment: AFAIK you can't transfer between JFK's terminals after going through security (except between terminals 2 and 4 where there is a shuttle bus).  So the question is, will security let you go through in Terminal 7 when your boarding pass says Terminal 8?  My guess is no, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Checking in luggage doesn't necessarily imply going through security. I imagine it's possible to go between the terminals land side, once luggage has been dropped. I've no idea how though!

Comment: Welcome new user!  A fascinating local-insider-knowledge question.  IDK the answer!

Answer (score 1):

There are two different cases:

a) the Alaska Airline lounge is landside, meaning you won't have to go through security to access it

b) the Alaska Airline lounge is airside, meaning you will have to go through security to access it

In case a), it is pretty simple; you check in in Terminal 7, then take the AirTrain to Terminal 8, enjoy the Lounge, get back to Terminal 7, through security and on you go.

In case b), you would do similarly, but have to go through security in Terminal 8. Assuming that you do have some credentials for accessing the Alaska Airline lounge, you would have to present them. If it makes you feel better, you might drop by at the Alaska Airline counter and get some kind of additional confirmation that you are entitled to go to the lounge.

Comment: While this admirably and absolutely perfectly explains the question, I guess, the OP is wanting to know which case it is eh!  :)

Comment: A very quick search (which I assumed that the OP has done) reveals that the lounge is airside, and there is no airside inter-terminal transportation. So, it is case b).